# Access denied in Workbench.aspx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I downloaded the `workbench.aspx` file and uploaded to office 365 SharePoint Online Developer site under "`Documents`" document library.

When I try to open the same, I page does not load correctly (I do not get option to add ClientWebPart) and I get below error in console window:

> Access is Denied
>
> File: SuiteServiceProxy.aspx, Line: 1, Column: 1

Comment: Are you using a developer tenant? You can't use the Workbench on a regular tenant.

Comment: Yes I am using a developer tenant.

Comment: And you have upgraded to the latest version of SPFx (drop 5) https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-Drop-5

Comment: Yes I have upgraded to the latest version of SPFx.

Answer (score 0):

For now (we're working on making this easier), make sure you add the column to the list before uploading the workbench (described here - https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant in the 'Set up a document library' section).